# Breeze.Sharp MVVM trying to get results from the database - error

Tags: c#, database, task, breeze-sharp

I am using Breeze.Sharp for getting entities out of the database. I am getting this error when trying to retrieve "result":

> Cannot find a default resource name for CLR type:
>   `AHS.Apps.Call.WPF.Entities.CallActionCategory`

I've stepped through the Breeze code but it has little documentation. Here is my method:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<CallActionCategory>> CallActionCategories()
{
    var query = EntityQuery.From<Entities.CallActionCategory>();

    IEnumerable<CallActionCategory> result = await (_entityManager.ExecuteQuery<Entities.CallActionCategory>(query));
    ObservableCollection<CallActionCategory> observe = new ObservableCollection<CallActionCategory>(result);         
    await _entityManager.FetchMetadata();

    return observe;
}
```

Comment: This happens if it cannot find the `EntityType` instance for your CLR type `AHS.Apps.Call.WPF.Entities.CallActionCategory` in the metadata, or the resource it is supposed to map against. i.e. your CLR type is not mapped correctly. Since you have not included any other information, such as the declaration of a `CallActionCategory` and how it maps to your backend (or what your backend is for that matter) there is no way of telling anything more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to breeze, I wasn't sure what else to include. I tried pasting a class here with the mapping but stack said it was too long. I have it mapped in the context in WPF. I have AHS.Apps.Call.WPF.Entities  mapped to AHS.Apps.Call.WPF.Entities which both contain the CallActionCategory and works fine other places like this. Also, it's important to note when I browse to the 'site' and look at metadata, all results are populated correctly. If there is any other information I can provide please let me know, and thank you very much for such a quick response.
`